# SimpleSAMLphp generate assertion

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, saml, simplesamlphp

I'm using `SimpleSAMLphp` as an `IdP` for a bunch of applications we have, chiefly a **Drupal** site. I've used SQL as an authsource on the `IdP` and that works to authenticate users, the response returns to **Drupal** and the users are authenticated. All good !

However we also need to use social login (login with Twitter, Facebook etc). **SimpleSAMLphp** supports **OAuth**, I've set it up and the login works on the **IdP** with the social accounts, **SimpleSAML** creates the session and cookies but I'm not authenticated on the Drupal site.

What I need to do is complete the request by returning to Drupal and authenticating the user there, that is, to issue an assertion back to Drupal on success.

Just like in the SQL source, I've mapped the attributes in each of the source files (Twitter.php, Facebook.php etc) however where SQL auth returns to Drupal and creates a session, the others just display their attributes in a template.

How do I generate and send back an assertion for **Drupal** from these social logins so as to authenticate my users there ?

`saml10-sp-remote.php (IdP)`

```
$metadata['https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/metadata.php/sp'] = array (
  'SingleLogoutService' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/sp',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:SOAP',
      'Location' => 'https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/sp',
    ),
  ),
  'AssertionConsumerService' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'index' => 0,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/sp',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'index' => 1,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post',
      'Location' => 'https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/sp',
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
      'index' => 2,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
      'Location' => 'https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/sp',
    ),
    3 =>
    array (
      'index' => 3,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01',
      'Location' => 'https://durpal_url/simplesaml_drupal_sp/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/sp/artifact',
    ),
  ),
  'certData' => 'xxxx',
);
```

`authsources.php (IdP)`

```
'sql' => array(
        'sqlauth:SQL',
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db',
        'username' => 'user',
        'password' => 'pass',
        'query' => 'SELECT u.uid, u.name, u.mail, r.name AS role FROM users u JOIN users_roles ur on ur.uid = u.uid JOIN role r on r.rid = ur.rid where u.mail = :username AND pass = MD5(:password);',
    ),

'facebook' => array(
    'authfacebook:Facebook',
    'api_key' => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx',
    'req_perms' => 'email',
),

'linkedin' => array(
    'authlinkedin:LinkedIn',
    'key' => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx',
),

'twitter' => array(
    'authtwitter:Twitter',
    'key' => 'xxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxx',
    'force_login' => true,
),
```

`saml20-idp-remote.php (SP, Drupal)`

```
$metadata['http://idp_url/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php'] = array (
  'metadata-set' => 'saml20-idp-remote',
  'entityid' => 'http://idp_url/simplesaml/saml2/idp/metadata.php',
  'SingleSignOnService' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://idp_url/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SSOService.php',
    ),
  ),
  'SingleLogoutService' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://idp_url/simplesaml/saml2/idp/SingleLogoutService.php',
    ),
  ),
  'certData' => 'xxx',
  'NameIDFormat' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient',
);
```

`saml20-idp-hosted.php (IdP)`

```
$metadata['__DYNAMIC:1__'] = array(
    'host' => '__DEFAULT__',
    'privatekey' => 'mysite.com.key',
    'certificate' => 'mysite.com.crt',
    'auth' => 'sql',
);
```

Comment: Post some of you config.  Is the IDP configured to use the social providers as the authsource?  It sounds you may have just configured additional authsources and not configured the IDP to use them.

Comment: @Patrick updated ! the IdP is configured to use social as authsource, the IdP points to the SP and the SP to the IdP. With this config, only using SQL authsource actually creates a session on Drupal

Comment: can you also include `saml20-idp-hosted.php` from your idp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Background

Your issue is that your Identity Provider is configured to use sql auth and not twitter, linkedin, etc. The drupal site will send you to the IDP and the IDP is only knowledgable about sql.  While you do have authsources configured for social, SSP lets you test and verify those independently of your IDP configuration. This is why SSP is just display the social attributes in a template, and not letting you log into drupal with them.

## Option A

[multiauth](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/1.14/multiauth:multiauth) will let you define an `authsource` that includes your social and sql. You then configure your idp to use the new multiauth authsource

## Option B

An IDP per social provider. We run an IDP per social provider. We have multiple IDPs (with unique entityIDs) define in `saml20-idp-hosted.php` - one for each social account. We do it this way because each of our SPs only wants to trust a subset of all configured social IDPs.

Each SP in this option would include the additional IDP data in `saml20-idp-remote.php`

## Option C

Outsource. We run this sort of social to saml gateway as a [SaaS product](http://www.cirrusidentity.com/gateway/). This makes sense if you don't like running things yourself, or if you have a several SPs that all want different social providers, or to use different social api keys/secrets per SP.